# UITextField inputView - IBActions not fired

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to replace the default keyboard of a `UITextField` with a custom keyboard. So I created a new subclass of a `UIViewController` with a xib-file (the other way like creating both files seperately and setting the File's Owner doesn't work either).

Then I added a button to the KeyboardView and connected it to an `IBAction`. After that I set the textfields inputView to the new view like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let keyboardVC = KeyboardViewController()
    textField.inputView = keyboardVC.view
    keyboardVC.view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight
    keyboardVC.delegate = textField
}
```

It's working and the custom keyboard shows up, but if I touch the button, the IBAction is not called. What's the problem in my setup? (I checked some examples and they all do it the same way).

**UPDATE:**

I now removed the ViewController and subclassed the UIView. Now the actions are working. Why isn't it working with a ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one holds the `UIViewController`- there is no reference to it after the `viewDidLoad()` ended, it is released from the memory.
When the button is pressed, the view controller that should response to the action is not exist -> you are holding only the view of the view controller as the `textField.inputView`.

Comment: That's what was my assumption after reading some similiar threads at stackoverflow. But: Why is there no `exc_bad_access`? (Just for my understanding) (and thanks for your answer)